# Android ADB 1.0.36 crashes while installing

Tags: android, adb

In some of our machines adb.exe (which is part of andorid sdk platform-tools) is crashing while closing. It successfully does so, but before closing we see that the exe is stopped working. The crash message detail are below:-

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   adb.exe
Application Version:    0.0.0.0
Application Timestamp:  34c434bd
Fault Module Name:  StackHash_7ca3
Fault Module Version:   6.3.9600.18233
Fault Module Timestamp: 56bb4e1d
Exception Code: c0000374
Exception Offset:   PCH_D9_FROM_ntdll+0x0003C7EC
OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.400.8
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   7ca3
Additional Information 2:   7ca3309415de3955a9cf25d10e5afbf2
Additional Information 3:   337d
Additional Information 4:   337ddf8c0ebbfe48ca581c27cf23a9aa
```

and another instance

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   adb.exe
Application Version:    0.0.0.0
Application Timestamp:  34c434bd
Fault Module Name:  StackHash_7ca3
Fault Module Version:   6.3.9600.18233
Fault Module Timestamp: 56bb4e1d
Exception Code: c0000374
Exception Offset:   PCH_D9_FROM_ntdll+0x0003C7EC
OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.400.8
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   7ca3
Additional Information 2:   7ca3309415de3955a9cf25d10e5afbf2
Additional Information 3:   337d
Additional Information 4:   337ddf8c0ebbfe48ca581c27cf23a9aa
```

From some google help,

- we tried doing sfc/scannow all was fine still error persisted,
- we tried excluding this exe from DEP (Data execution prevention) still no help,
- we also tried clean boot, but nothing worked.

Comment: did resolve this issue